# How can I have Windows 10 silently check a web site every few minutes?

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I want to have my home theater PC check for internet connectivity.  I have a monitoring service which has a receiving url that it, in turn, monitors.  So if it doesn't see a client connect to that URL after X minutes, it flags an alert.

So, I need Windows 10 to check a site frequently.  In linux, I can accomplish this with something like:

```
* * * * * curl --silent "https://foo.blah" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What would the Windows 10 equivalent be?  I see that scheduled tasks are available but they don't seem to have the frequency I need.

Comment: "What would the Windows 10 equivalent be?" - A Powershell cmdlet similar to curl which does exist.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn't aware of the powershell option.  I just tried going through the `create task` and `create basic task` options in the Task Scheduler UI.

Comment: When using the task scheduler, you'll need to call the powershell executable, and use the script as an argument. There are already questions here on that topic. So all you need to figure out is getting CURL on your system.

Comment: You can do this natively in [task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250516/2505109)

Answer (score 1):

**curl**

[curl is available on Windows](https://curl.se/download.html) (though you may have to scroll a bit =P). I would personally recommend the [official Windows builds](https://curl.se/windows/) or perhaps the builds by [Dirk Paehl](https://www.paehl.com/). The curl version number in blue is the link to the appropriate file/download page.

Regarding the command itself (minus cron), you can substitute the Windows [NUL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) device for /dev/null :

```
curl --silent "https://foo.blah" > nul 2>&1
```

*Note: Regarding execution (below), this line can be placed in a simple batch file or as part of a script.*

**Task Scheduler**

> I see that scheduled tasks are available but they don't seem to have the frequency I need.

[It is possible to use Windows Task Scheduler to repeat tasks every X minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249542/run-a-task-every-x-minutes-with-windows-task-scheduler).

In short, you can:

- Schedule a new task and set it to be run Daily (every 24hrs starting at e.g. 12:00 PM and set to *Recur every 1 days*) under the task *Properties → Triggers* tab.
- Under the *Advanced* section, check the *Repeat task every* option and set the desired repetitions. The smallest dropdown unit is 5 minutes but you can simply edit it to be 1 minute by typing in the field.
- Under the *Settings* tab (still under *Properties*), make sure to check *Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed*.

The one drawback to this method is that if a scheduled start time is missed, there is a 10 minute delay before "Run task as soon as possible" (above) kicks in.

**cron**

Another option is to try a cron replacement such as [CRONw](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/). Its older and I haven't personally tried it unfortunately, but it might be worth checking out. However, I would recommend [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/) rather than ActiveState Perl if you do.

As a final personal recommendation, [Intelliadmin cron](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2012/05/free-utility-a-simple-task-scheduler-for-windows/) may also suit your needs. It nicely bridges the gap between something like Task Scheduler and cron. You can download a copy from the [Intelliadmin downloads page](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/downloads/) from the link marked as "Windows Cron Service 2.0" (which downloads Intelliadmin cron as *iadmincron.exe*). This executable installs the Intelliadmin cron service and a management interface, which are both very light and utilitarian.